# Heroku costum domain only working on mac side

Tags: heroku, dns

I set a custom domain to my Heroku app, by

1. Setting a cname on my domain: appname.herokuapp.com
2. Added my www.domain.com, by: heroku domains:add www.domain.com

It works fine in Safari and Firefox, but somehow it doesent work on the windows side. It forwards to the Heroku adress instead.

What can be the problem ? 
Thanks